# Can't explain why "if else" in PHP doesn't work properly

Tags: php, sql

Here's the form handling

```
if(isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM md5dictionary");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(strlen($_POST['keywords']) < 1 || ctype_space($_POST['keywords']) == true) {
        $errors['blank'] = "<span class='error'> Please insert a word </span>";
    } else {
        $newword = $_POST['keywords'];
        $db_checkExist = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM md5dictionary WHERE keywords="' . $newword . '"');
        echo mysql_num_rows($db_checkExist) . "<br />";
        if(mysql_num_rows($db_checkExist) > 0) {
            echo "outside else " . mysql_num_rows($db_checkExist);
            $finalResult = "<span class='error'> Failed!!! </span>";
        } else {
            echo "inside else " . mysql_num_rows($db_checkExist);
            $md51 = md5($newword);
            $md52 = md5($md51);
            mysql_query('INSERT INTO md5dictionary(keywords, mdFive, mdFive2) VALUES ("' . $newword . '", "' . $md51 . '", "' . $md52 . '")');
            $finalResult = "<span class='success'> Thank you! Wanna add another one? </span>";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset> Input Form </fieldset>
    <label for="keywords"> Input new Keywords into dictionary: </label>
     <?php echo $finalResult; ?>
     <?php echo $errors['blank']; ?>
        <input name="keywords" type="text" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add!!" />
        <input name="clear" type="submit" value="Clear Database" />
</form>
<h1> Datas: </h1>
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM md5dictionary");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {
        echo "Data " . $i . "<br />";
        echo "keywords: " . mysql_result($result, $i, "keywords") . "<br />";
        echo "md5: " . mysql_result($result, $i, "mdFive") . "<br />";
        echo "md5_2: " . mysql_result($result, $i, "mdFive2") . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Here's the result: http://md5dictionary.hoangminhdat.com

Question: Why it keeps saying "Failed!" Why it has successfully insert information into my database?
There should be no spelling mistake

I know it will be time-consuming go through my dumb question but plss, i can't explain it myself!!

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem.

Comment: I see no error. And your site is asking for **SQL INJECTION!**

Comment: I noticed that somebody did alert something out from my page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean when you say it inserts and it gives "fail".
Do you actually mean "INSERT INTO md5dictionary..." is executed, AND you have the " Failed!!! " code showing?

If this is so, I recommend you investiguate and revise your form flows since it is most probable that calling itself, the form tries to run twice, the second time having null values.

This is what I coming up with.

Have a good day,
S.

Comment: I think this is the problem... Thank you very very much. Haven't figure out how to fix it but at least i know where i did wrong. Thanks again

Comment: The form runs twice logically explain the problem! But why it runs twice? How can i fix it?

Comment: One thing you could do, for tests purposes, is to cut/paste into a brand new php file the php process part of your form. Then in your form definition of course you also have to change the action consequently. There, you'll be able to call the script pressing the submit button, and only once. See the results after that.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the weblink you provided.

If I insert a word then I get 'inside else' and it looks like it's inserted.

If I quickly enter this word again then I get 'failed'.

So I see no problem, isn't this what you want to achieve ?
Otherwise please rethink your question and refine what is not working for you and when.

**EDIT:**
If you want the successful message then you need another:

```
echo $finalResult;
```

after you defined $finalResult.

Comment: What i wanna archive is that when it's successfully insert data, it will echo out the success message

Comment: Then you forgot the 
'echo $finalResult'!

Comment: I did echo it out in the form, under the label